# Formal definition of episodic Markov Decision process?

Tags: reference-request, markov-chains, definitions, hidden-markov-models

David Silver, in his [lecture 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PnHCvfgC_ZA) from his Youtube lectures, speaks about episodic Markov Decision Processes (MDPs) and Monte-Carlo Policy Evaluation.

I could not find a formal definition of episodic MDPs and episodes.

Can someone provide the definition for both episodic MDPs and episodes?

Comment: Hi, welcome to MO. (A) What slides are you referring to? Could you give a link? (B) In the last paragraph you suddenly ask an entirely new question with concepts ('model-free policy evaluation', for example) which you don't define and have nothing to do with the question. I think you should erase it and perhaps put it in a new, more better formed, post.

Comment: @AmirSagiv is my question clear now?

Comment: Much more, great!

Comment: From my understanding they are Markov Chains that finish after a series of steps. This is what I finally understood after reading a number of lectures. This way one can collect statistics during them and have monte carlo of first or every visit.